# How to redirect to new page on successful Facebook authentication

Tags: firebase, ionic2, firebase-authentication, facebook-authentication

I have a following code for Facebook authentication using firebase. On Successful authentication I need to redirect to new page. I tried to check inside if token is not null then window.redirect function but it is not working. Can anybody please help me. Thank you.

```
facebookLogin(){
    // Sign in using a redirect.
    firebase.auth().getRedirectResult().then(function(result) {
        console.log(result);
      if (result.credential) {
        // This gives you a Google Access Token.
        var token = result.credential.accessToken;
      }
      var user = result.user;
    })
    // Start a sign in process for an unauthenticated user.
    var provider = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();
    firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect(provider);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably `navController.setRoot(NewPage)` or `navController.push(NewPage)` in the callback from your authentication.

See [the `NavController` documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

You should use **arrow functions** (`()=> {...}`) instead of standard functions (`function(){...}`), so the `this` keyword still references the component code instead of the function itself. That way you can still use properties and method defined in your component inside of that function.

```
facebookLogin(){
    // Sign in using a redirect.
    firebase.auth().getRedirectResult().then((result) => { // <--- Here!
      console.log(result);
      if (result.credential) {
        // This gives you a Google Access Token.
        var token = result.credential.accessToken;
      }
      var user = result.user;

      // Now you can use the methods and properties from your component here!
      this.navCtrl.setRoot(NextPage);

    });
    // Start a sign in process for an unauthenticated user.
    var provider = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();
    firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect(provider);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To redirect to a new page on successful authentication -

1. Create a function to be loaded on page load -

   ```
   function initApp() {
       firebase.auth().getRedirectResult().then(function (result) {
           if (result.credential) {
               window.location='newpage.html';//Replace with your newpage URL
           }
       }

   }
   window.onload = function () {
       initApp();        
   };
   ```

   Note - Script with `window.onload` function should be on the page where facebook login method given in point 2 below is invoked from.

2.(Recommended) Keep the provider invocation script separate in another function -

```
function signInWithFacebook() {
    var provider = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();
    firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect(provider);
}
```